# took to drinking OR started to drink

Tags: gerunds

Which phrase can replace the bold part,if its incorrect.

1. The woman left her husband immediately after he lost his job and he **took to drink** alcohol excessively.

a. started to drink

b. took to drinking (Book answer)

As I know "start" takes both gerund and infinitive. So why "started to drink" is incorrect here?

Can "started drinking" be a possible alternative answer of bold part?

Comment: **to take to something*** is an idiom. With started to drink, you probably would not  use the word alcohol, as it is understood. So, the clue is the word alcohol. Pretty tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *drinking* when you refer to repetitive consumption over some period of time. For example:

> Let's go out **drinking**.
>   He started **drinking** excessively.

as opposed to:

> I'll have a **drink** after dinner.

*took to* indicates the beginning of some behavior continuing over time.

Comment: Can we use "started drinking" here?